# Framed box, over framed text with image

Tags: graphics, boxes, mdframed, tcolorbox

[image]

Hi all,
I'm a newby in LaTeX but after researching online, I have seen that it is possible to create boxes and frames adjusted to text and images. I am trying to achieve something like the image, what would you recommend? I have seen you can use `\ovalbox`, `mdframed`, `beamer`, `TiKZ`… My main issue is framing the title in the position required and insert image.
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with `tcolorbox` and `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.61,0.73,0.35}


\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{
    \node[fill=mygreen,
        rounded corners,
        draw=white,
        line width=2pt,
        drop shadow,
        text width=4cm,
        inner sep=8pt,
        xshift=-2cm]
    at (frame.north){\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#1}};
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    overlay={\mytitle{#2}},
    borderline={2pt}{0mm}{mygreen},
    borderline={.7pt}{1mm}{mygreen},
    frame hidden,
    arc=3mm,
    sidebyside,
    lefthand width=2.5cm,
    segmentation hidden,
    top=15pt,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Political Factors}
    \includegraphics[scale=.1]{lion.jpg}
    \tcblower
    Analyses to what degree the government intervenes
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument in the `newtcolorbox` is there in case you need to apply different customizations to specific boxes (e.g., you could have the same box with a different background color with `\begin{mybox}[colback=red]{Political Factors}`. It is ignored otherwise, as in the given MWE.

Comment: Woah! I have been playing around with these packages and it's amazing the things you can do with them. Thank you so much for your help. You have really provided me a head start for Latex use! :) Thanks thanks!!

Comment: @user41232 you're welcome, have fun with LaTeX :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a possible `mdframed` approach. I used the package `mwe` just so that the code will compile. I have made liberal use of the picture you provided for the image, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.61,0.73,0.35}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
    innerlinewidth = 0.5pt,
    outerlinewidth = 2pt,
    linecolor = mygreen,
    tikzsetting = {draw = white, line width = 0.5pt},
    roundcorner=15pt,
    linecolor=mygreen,
    linewidth=2pt,
    topline=true,
    frametitleaboveskip=1.5\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,
}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\mdfsetup{%
    style = mystyle,
    }}%
    {\mdfsetup{%
    style = mystyle,
    frametitle={%
    \tikz{[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
    \node[draw = white, line width = 2pt, text = white, anchor=east,rectangle,
    fill=mygreen, rounded corners, drop shadow]
    {\strut #1};
    }}}}%
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Political Factors]
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
Analyses to what degree the government intervenes in the
economy. It includes regulations and legal issues and defines
both formal and informal rules under which the firm must
operate. Political factors include: tax policy, employment laws,
environmental regulations, trade restriction tariffs and political
stability.
\end{minipage}%
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!! I'm now further investigating about the mwe package... really versatile! :) Thanks a lot for your help!